# Creating custom combination from two lists

Tags: python-3.5

I am looking to use two lists:

```
L1 = ['a', 's', 'd']
L2 = [str(1), str(2)]
```

I need to create a third list:

```
L3 = [(a1, s1, d1), (a1, s1, d2), ... ]
```

L3 has tuples of size 3 where each tuple has only non-repetitive elements from L1 but can have repetitive elements from L2.

i.e. a pair as `(a1, s2, d2)` is allowed but `(a1, a2, d1)` is not allowed.

`L3` has tuples of size 3.

I am working with large `L1` and `L2` so the above example is only for illustration. I am not sure how to approach this problem. I have thought about using `itertools` `permutation` and `combination` modules but I am not getting the list `L3` above. One brute force solution is to do something as:

```
L3 = list(itertools.combinations(list(itertools.product(L1, L2)), 3))
```

and then condition out the elements as `('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('d', '2')` but for a large combination that is not efficient for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it sounds like you want L1 to be the first elements of the tuples, I think we simply need to zip them, not iter-anything them.  We only need to take the product of L2.

```
In [327]: [list(zip(L1, p)) for p in itertools.product(L2, repeat=len(L1))]
Out[327]: 
[[('a', '1'), ('s', '1'), ('d', '1')],
 [('a', '1'), ('s', '1'), ('d', '2')],
 [('a', '1'), ('s', '2'), ('d', '1')],
 [('a', '1'), ('s', '2'), ('d', '2')],
 [('a', '2'), ('s', '1'), ('d', '1')],
 [('a', '2'), ('s', '1'), ('d', '2')],
 [('a', '2'), ('s', '2'), ('d', '1')],
 [('a', '2'), ('s', '2'), ('d', '2')]]
```

where you can replace `[` and `]` with `(` and `)` to turn the listcomp into a genexp if you don't want to materialize the whole object at once.

If you want to merge your tuples' elements into one string, you could do that too:

```
In [338]: gen = (tuple(''.join(pair) for pair in zip(L1, p)) 
                 for p in itertools.product(L2, repeat=len(L1)))

In [339]: for elem in gen:
     ...:     print(elem)
('a1', 's1', 'd1')
('a1', 's1', 'd2')
('a1', 's2', 'd1')
('a1', 's2', 'd2')
('a2', 's1', 'd1')
('a2', 's1', 'd2')
('a2', 's2', 'd1')
('a2', 's2', 'd2')
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please add example using genexp ? Also how do I create ('a1', 's1', 'd1') from above?

Comment: @Zanam: just to be clear, you want me to replace the brackets with parentheses for you?

Comment: I thought genexp would be some convoluted code that I can learn from. I didn't think it was just changing parentheses.

Comment: Nope, here it literally is just changing `[]` for `()`.  After that you have a generator, and while you can't index into it any more, you can call `next(gen)` to get the next element or loop over it using a `for` loop.